# Multer Only Reading Undefined

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I cannot for the life of me get multer's fileupload working. I've read dozens of tutorials, followed YT guides, and scoured dozens of StackOverflow questions, but cannot get the thing to work through Postman.

This is the route's page, with the route being /image-upload.

Here's the complete code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const multer = require('multer');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

let path = require('path');


var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, __dirname + '../uploads')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
    }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    let file = req.file;
    console.log(req.file);
    console.log(req.files);
    if (!file) {
        return res.json({nofile: 'please upload a file'})
    }
})

module.exports = router;
```

It's not a file size issue, as the file size is 46KB. I get undefined when I console.log(req.file), yet I get the full data details when I do: console.log(req.files). In Postman, it just returns the json error, as if the file isn't even being read by multer.
In postman I'm correctly using form-data, to the POST route, and the file field name is: image, like I state in the POST route.

Comment: This is specific to the middleware of the library you're using. What's the problem with reading the file data from the `files` instead of `file`? I think the file should be somewhere in the `files`. See the name property of input that's sending the file. The file should be at `files.<name_of_input_that_is_sending_the_file>`

Comment: Hey Dragos, thanks for replying! The documentation and tutorials all say to use: req.file instead of req.files. And the name of the input is: image like I state in the POST request, so I'm not sure why it's not working. When I change it to req.files.image (like you mentioned) it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it! Express-fileupload was the issue. When you use express-fileupload in the file, it reserves req.file. Therefore the Multer middleware cannot access it. By removing that, I was able to fix it and upload it properly.